# Generate nugetpackage for android class library vs 2017

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, nuget-package

I have noticed that when using a specific library eg "android class library" or ios one there is no option to automatically generate the nuget package ,this option is available for std class library.

How can i quickly generate a nuget package for my android of ios class library?

Comment: You could not bind a iOS Library to an Android project because they run in different platforms.If you can not find the library from NuGet.You can incorporate Java libraries into your Xamarin.Android application by creating a Bindings Library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: @MonkeySteve The auther's intention is not to use native libraries, but to create platform-spcific libraries, that are available over nuget. Just like [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin).

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?